# facebook connect Fb.getLoginStatus from php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm building an app with multiple subdomain for my users, since the Facebook JS SDK don't allow wildcard on Authorized domains for the JavaScript SDK in App settings, I created an auth.example.com where I can authorize users with the php-sdk and save token in db I'm wondering if there is a way I can use the JS SDK with the access token from server-side, to be able to use the different methods of the JS SDK Such as `FB.getLoginStatus`, `FB.login`, `FB.logout` ..., I tried to create the same cookie from the server-side but the php-sdk doesn't return the `signed request` Any suggestions ?

Comment: I doubt messing with the cookies will get you anywhere, and that is really not something you should even attempt in the first place. The SDK knows what domain it is currently embedded on, it can simply take that info from the location object. Your setup is simply not suitable to use the client-side SDK.

Comment: So I can only relay on the PHP SDK for the logout and permission refresh ?

Comment: Yes, most likely.

Comment: Okay that help's a lot thank you, @CBroe